# return elements separated by comm from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello I have an array like this

```
const persons = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Rick'}, {name: 'Amy'}]
```

I would like to separate  it with comma and add "and" before the last element

```
John, Rick and Amy
```

I can do

```
persons.map(person => <span>{person.name}, </span>)
```

but that will generate

```
John, Rick, Amy,
```

is there a more efficient (fancy) way of doing this instead of iterating the array and add "," before all elements except the last one?

Answer (score 2):

Let try with simple check with conditions following index of element:

```js
const persons = [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Rick'}, {name: 'Amy'}]
const formmatted = persons.map((p,i) => (p.name + (i === persons.length - 2 ? ' and ' : (i !== persons.length - 1 ? ', ' : '')))).join("");
console.log(formmatted);
```